# SMTP server can't send emails from hosting c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, email, hosting

Good day to everyone. I've writen a project based on asp.net mvc3. Part of project is based on sending emails from my application.

```
public void SendEmail(string address, string subject, string message, int id)
{
        string email = "emailname@gmail.com";
        string password = "somepassword";

        var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
        var msg = new MailMessage();
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        msg.From = new MailAddress(email);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = message;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/Content/StudentPdf/student" + id + ".pdf")));

        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = loginInfo;
        smtpClient.Send(msg);

}
```

This code works locally, perfectly sending emails. But when I upload this to the hosting, it causes an error

> the SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

I've tried to change port to 465, but then it will be get me an tcp_ip error on the hosting. And one more: and when users try to send emails from this mailbox google tell me that suspicious activity on the application. It's because my hosting in one country and I am in another country.

I have no idea what I have to do next. I've tried googling and found something about 2 level registration, but don't understand how I need implement it in my method.

I'm using arvixe hosting.  Maybe others have the same problems?

Comment: Did you exceed the daily email limit? Google's SMTP only permits a couple hundred emails to be sent each day. When you exceed that, you get the exact error message you described.

Comment: No, How I can exceed daily limit if i can't send no one mail? And locally everything work perfect

Comment: And all mails which i send today locally from this account not greater than 20

Comment: Insted of var msg try MailMessage msg and Replace var smtpClient with SmtpClient smtpClient and try.

Comment: I tryed, but nothing happened. The same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please login into your gmail account manually and allow the IP of your hosting under gmail settings.Thats why i think its working perfectly on your local.
Same happened with me and after doing this there was no problem.

Comment: Please may you tell me where i can allow ip?

Comment: When it happened with me ,gmail showed me a red bar on top after login saying that an unauthorized access was made,when i clicked on that bar it took me to page where it confirmed whether you identify this activity(with the IP),i confirmed it ,then it started working fine.

Comment: And google still write in the log that The login attempt from an application or from the device is locked but didnt mark it, only write in the log.